# Getting foreign key error on deletion

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have the following models in django:

```
class ItemInstance(models.Model):
    item_type = models.ForeignKey('ItemContentType', related_name='item_type')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class TerritoryPricing(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(ItemInstance, null=True)
    territory = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

However, when I delete an `ItemInstance`, I always get an IntegrityError. Here is an example error:

```
>>> ItemInstance.objects.filter(pk=123).delete()
```

> IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`avails`.`main_territorypricing`, CONSTRAINT `main_territorypricing_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `main_iteminstance` (`id`))')

This just started happening recently, so perhaps there is some cached information in my django app or django db. How can I go about fixing this? For now, what I have to do is:

```
>>> TerritoryPricing.objects.filter(item__pk=123) # so no FK error
>>> ItemInstance.objects.filter(pk=123)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not have `null=True` in the Foreign Key definition, but rather have the model handle that itself:

```
item = models.ForeignKey(ItemInstance, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

This will fix the FK error you have above.

Comment: You must add 'null=True' into the line. Unless you will meet another error message.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a referencial integrity error because the ForeignKey does not specify an `on_delete` action for the FK field in the child row. Try setting `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` for example, to set the FK field to `NULL` after deletion of the related object:

```
item = models.ForeignKey(ItemInstance, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

You'll need to make migrations and apply them to update the field in your DB.

Comment: thanks for this -- I still get the same error when doing this.

Comment: @David542 Migrations made and applied?

Comment: yup, still getting the same error, so not sure why it's occurring. I feel like there's caching information somewhere in the app so that it's calling a FK that is perhaps not there.

Comment: for whatever reason, this error had to do with having `null=True`. I removed this and it worked. Any idea why that caused the error?